# Alternative in Python for apply method on creating a new train dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, apply

In the process of making a train method I observed that .apply method is way way too slow. It would be nice if someone can recommend another method which is semnificantly faster because I am talking about len =~ 3.5 milions.

train2.head() looks like this

```
    Email   SaleDate            NetGrossEUR
0       2018-01-01 00:37:04 32.195298
1       2018-01-01 01:11:53 225.391230
2       2018-01-01 01:17:47 0.000000
3       2018-01-01 01:21:08 0.000000
4       2018-01-01 02:18:48 0.000000
```

```
def compute_rfm(x, end_calibration): 
    x['recency'] = (x['SaleDate'].max() - x['SaleDate'].min()).days
    x['frequency'] = x['SaleDate'].count()-1
    x['T'] = (end_calibration - x['SaleDate'].min()).days
    x['monetary_value'] = x['SaleDate'].mean()
    return x
```

this compiled quite faster, but this is taking way too long:

```
train3 = train2.groupby(['Email']).apply(lambda x: compute_rfm(x, end_calibration))
```

If that particular code would have compiled then I would expected something like this:

```
    cust    date    sales   recency frequency     T          monetary_value
0   4   1997-01-18  29.73   328     2               347          23.723333
1   4   1997-08-02  14.96   328     2               347          23.723333
2   4   1997-12-12  26.48   328     2               347          23.723333
3   18  1997-01-04  14.96   0       0               361          14.960000
4   21  1997-01-01  63.34   12      1               364          37.555000
```

Comment: You compute your `x['SaleDate'].min()` twice in your `compute_rfm` function. You could try to store it in a variable to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing it by passing the dataframe itself to a function. For example, like this:

```
def compute_rfm(train2, end_calibration):
    x = train2.groupby(['Email'])['SaleDate'].agg(['max', 'min', 'count']).reset_index()
    x['recency'] = (x['max'] - x['min']).dt.days
    x['frequency'] = x['count']-1
    x['T'] = (end_calibration - x['SaleDate'].min()).days
    y = train2.groupby(['Email'])['NetGrossEur'].agg(['mean']).reset_index()
    x = x.merge(y, on = 'Email', how = 'outer')
    return x
```

And then call the function:

```
train3 = compute_rfm(train2, end_calibration)
```

There were times, this was faster for me than using `apply`. Let me know if it works in your case for millions of records.

Comment: well...this crashed my aws lol. I will try again and let you know.

Comment: Ooops, sorry for that. Was just a suggestion because at times this was faster for me. Apologies again!

Comment: lol no worries, it happens to me everytime, obviously when working with data from to 3-30 milions. rofl